# reverse engineer a physical data model from a SAP HANA Calculation View in PowerDesigner

Tags: multidimensional-array, data-modeling, hana, powerdesigner

I created a multidimensional data model in SAP HANA as a calculation view type Cube with star join. In this calculation view I only used calculation views type Dimension, which include the dimension tables and the necessary changes I made to them (e.g. building hierarchies).

I now need to present a conceptual data model with all the dependencies. In PowerDesigner it is possible to reverse engineer physical data models, but when I try to do as it is described by SAP I get the physical tables as a result without the connections. I imported all calculation views and the necessary tables.

Does this happen because I did not connect the tables itself and only the views and is there a way to solve this?

Thank you very much for reading this. :)

Answer (score 0):

SAP PowerDesigner can read the SAP HANA information models [online help: Calculation Views (HANA)](https://help.sap.com/viewer/5b9c2c4e13a94769bff7cfa6524dac68/16.6.4/en-US/009051bbd8e747aaba8bf024edb0cc5e.html).
This allows for impact analysis, i.e. the dependencies to source tables and views are captured.
However, the SAP HANA information views are usually not considered part of a logical data model as they are rather parts of analytical applications.

As for the lack of join conditions in the reverse engineered data model: if the model is reversed from the database runtime objects, that is the tables and views currently in the database, then you won't commonly find that foreign key constraints are implemented as database constraints.

Instead, SAP products implement the join definition either in the application layer (SAP Netweaver dictionary) or in the repository via view definitions and CDS associations.

See [PowerDesigner and HANA](https://help.sap.com/viewer/5b9c2c4e13a94769bff7cfa6524dac68/16.6.4/en-US) for details on this.